# java internal method signature doesn't match constructor parameters (javap)

Tags: java, bytecode, javap

I have the following class containing local inner class:

```java
class Outer {
    private boolean beep;
    private int foo;

    public Outer(boolean beep) {
        this.beep = beep;
    }

    public void start(boolean beep) {
        class LocalInner {
            private LocalInner() {

            }
            public void method() {
                System.out.println("Test.");
                if (beep) {
                    System.out.println("beeping.");
                }
            }
        }

        LocalInner li = new LocalInner();
        li.method();
    }
}
```

When I compile the class `javac Outer.class`, and then check compiled members of `Outer$1LocalInner` with `javap -private Outer\$1LocalClass.class`, I get this:

```
class Outer$1LocalInner {
  final boolean val$beep;
  final Outer this$0;
  Outer$1LocalInner();
  public void method();
}
```

I was expecting that the constructor will be compiled to: `Outer$1LocalInner(Outer, boolean)`. When I tried to have a look at the byte code `javap -c -s -private Outer$1LocalInner.class` I got this:

```
class Outer$1LocalInner {
  final boolean val$beep;
    descriptor: Z
                                                                                                         
  final Outer this$0;
    descriptor: LOuter;
                                                                                                         
  Outer$1LocalInner();
    descriptor: (LOuter;Z)V
    Code:                    
       0: aload_0   
       1: aload_1
       2: putfield      #1                  // Field this$0:LOuter;   
       5: aload_0
       6: iload_2
       7: putfield      #2                  // Field val$beep:Z
      10: aload_0                                                                                        
      11: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
      14: return 
                                                                                                         
...
}
```

Now this is rather interesting! Let's have a closer look at these two lines:

```
  Outer$1LocalInner();
    descriptor: (LOuter;Z)V
```

1. Why is there no parameters to `Outer$1LocalInner()` constructor, yet I can see in the method descriptor that it does accept two parameters as I'm expecting `Outer` and `boolean`?
2. Why does the compiler ignores the access modifier of the local inner class? I'm declaring it as private, yet the disassembled version is package modifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s seems, `javac` generates a [`Signature` Attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.9):

> A `Signature` attribute stores a signature ([§4.7.9.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.9.1)) for a class, interface, constructor, method, field, or record component whose declaration in the Java programming language uses type variables or parameterized types.

This purpose doesn’t match the scenario, as this local class does use type variables or parameterized types, but we can show that the behavior of `javap` matches.

E.g., when we run `javap -s java.util.function.Supplier`, we get

```
Compiled from "Supplier.java"
public interface java.util.function.Supplier<T> {
  public abstract T get();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/Object;
}
```

showing that `javap` prints the method declaration as seen by the generic type system while printing the descriptor as used by the JVM is the second line. Which implies that is uses the information from the `Signature` attribute when printing the method declaration.

We can even force `javap` to print the `Signature` attribute.
Using `javap -v java.util.function.Supplier`:

```
[class declaration and constant pool omitted]
  public abstract T get();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/Object;
    flags: (0x0401) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_ABSTRACT
    Signature: #8                           // ()TT;
}
Signature: #9                           // <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>Ljava/lang/Object;
SourceFile: "Supplier.java"
RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
  0: #13()
    java.lang.FunctionalInterface
```

Note the line `Signature: #8 // ()TT;`

When I run `javap -p -v my.test.Outer$1LocalInner` with your example, I get

```
…
  private my.test.Outer$1LocalInner();
    descriptor: (Lmy/test/Outer;Z)V
    flags: (0x0002) ACC_PRIVATE
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=3, args_size=3
         0: aload_0
         1: aload_1
         2: putfield      #1                  // Field this$0:Lmy/test/Outer;
         5: aload_0
         6: iload_2
         7: putfield      #7                  // Field val$beep:Z
        10: aload_0
        11: invokespecial #11                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
        14: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 31: 0
        line 33: 14
    Signature: #16                          // ()V
…
```

which is consistent with the theory that the method has a `Signature` attribute reporting `()V` which leads to `javap` printing a declaration with no parameters.

Using this attribute for encoding the constructor’s source code appearance, even when it is not using type variables or generic types, has not been mentioned as a purpose of this attribute and Eclipse’s compiler does not generate such an attribute.

Note that [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.9) also says:

> Oracle's Java Virtual Machine implementation does not check the well-formedness of Signature attributes during class loading or linking. Instead, Signature attributes are checked by methods of the Java SE Platform class libraries which expose generic signatures of classes, interfaces, constructors, methods, and fields.

So the presence or absence of this attribute has no direct impact on the execution of the code. But when I append the following code to the end of your `start` method

```java
try {
    Constructor<?> c = li.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(Outer.class, boolean.class);
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(c.getParameterTypes()));
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(c.getGenericParameterTypes()));
} catch(ReflectiveOperationException ex) {}
```

it prints

```
[class my.test.Outer, boolean]
[class my.test.Outer, boolean]
```

when compiled with Eclipse and

```
[class my.test.Outer, boolean]
[]
```

when compiled with `javac`, showing that `getGenericParameterTypes()` interprets this `Signature` attribute.

---

All tests above where made with JDK 17. Since JDK 11, the outer class can access the `private` constructor directly and therefore, the constructor declared as `private` is compiled as `private`.

Prior to JDK 11, the `private` modifier gets removed for a local class. This is different from nonlocal nested classes, where `javac` keeps the `private` modifier and generates another non-`private` delegating constructor.

Answer (score 0):

1. Trust the descriptor. It's possible that javap isn't expanding the ctor parameters in the line above because it understands that this is an inner class and that the source code had no such special parameters declared.
2. This might depend on the Java version that you compiled against. Java 11 supports nestmates, and so it doesn't need to downgrade to package-private modifiers.

Comment: Actually a nested inner class is dealt with differently! A private class is change to package access modifier, the private constructor is kept private but a new package access modifier constructor is auto-generated just to call the private one.